# Database query - Order by, Group by and distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

This is how my database looks like

```
id|ordernumber|mainnumber|category| other fields`

1 | Q123      |Q123      |Home    | **
1 | Q123.1    |Q123      |Home    | **
1 | Q123.2    |Q123      |Home    | **
1 | Q124      |Q123      |Music   | **
1 | Q124.1    |Q123      |Music   | **
1 | Q124.2    |Q123      |Music   | **
1 | Q124.3    |Q123      |Music   | **
```

So to explain, the DB has product lists and variants and their category and other data.A product may or may not have variants. Each product has different number of variants.
The database is very huge, and I want to export it into chunks of around 10k rows with these constraints

- Approx 10k lines.
- Should be sorted by categories
- Should be grouped by the category
- Main product and variant should be in the same file. i.e half of a product variant should not be in one file, and rest in the other.

I can otherwise do like, take `DISTINCT` 9000 products based on main number,`ordered by category` and `grouped by category`, but I want all the rows with that main number.

Any help?

DB is kind of huge. 1,500,000k Rows.

Where I am now is at the start:

```
SELECT * from table GROUP BY `mainnumber` ORDER BY `category`  LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: You should not use group by without aggregate functions.

Comment: Besides what @P.Salmon said, you  would use `.. GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ..` order and not `... ORDER BY ... GROUP BY ... ` i assume this is a *"copy/paste"* error in your question??   Also it seams when looking into the example data you should ideally normalize your data as your are using your RDMS now as a spreadsheet instead..

Comment: I am not copy pasting.I just typed the query out of my mind, but I am sure that is enough to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: As @P.Salmon mentioned, I see no need to use any grouping for this query. What's your distribution for each main section? Does the number for each differ drastically? Why don't you just select 1 or 2 or n main categories at a time. Keeping the number close to 10k will be very complicated in SQL and overall it adds some unnecessary complexity even if you do it programmatically.

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan - It can change drastically. 0-150. Can I do this instead, Select 5000 unique main products with all variations from results sorted by category

Comment: *"I am not copy pasting.I just typed the query out of my mind, but I am sure that is enough to do what I am trying to do. "* No this query misuses [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) syntax for sure and it is just plain wrong, it is wrong as MySQL with `SELECT * ... GROUP BY category` can not use [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) on unique keys and from the example data is it very very clear that the `category` column does not has a unique key..

Comment: Can this be done? Select 5000 unique main products with all variations from results sorted by category? 5000 DISTINCT main products with all its variations (variations have same main number) from rows ordered by category

Comment: *"Can this be done?"* To many unknown columns in the example data with constraints, it is good that you tryed to simplify, but it sometimes does not make it more easy to give solid suggestions or a answer for that matter..

Comment: ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to try that make it more real like with smaller sizes for example a example with 50-100 records in a sqlfiddle  and expected results with 10 records as batch in separated ascii data tables would greatly help us to get a much better feeling

Comment: @Kishor yup you can easily do it. Just select as many distinct main products as you want and join the result with subcategories. That way you can implement paging on the main products.

Comment: Suggestion is: First make a query that gives you a distinct list of main products and their count of variants sorted by category. Then iterate the list, collect the number of products to reach ~10,000 output lines and get the data for these products and export them to a file. Make sure there is are appropriate indexes on Category and MainNumber